# Retrieve value of @odata.id with jq in Redfish output

Tags: json, jq

I'm parsing some json Redfish data using jq.

Trying to pull value for @odata.id from redfish.txt file below.

Invoking with recommended jq .["@odata.id"] doesn't seem to quite work to pull just value itself which is: /redfish/v1/Systems

Any suggestions welcomed. Output below... :)

Thanks,
Nick

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/opt# cat redfish.txt
{"@odata.context":"/redfish/v1/$metadata#ServiceRoot.ServiceRoot","@odata.id":"/redfish/v1","@odata.type":"#ServiceRoot.v1_2_0.ServiceRoot","AccountService":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/AccountService"},"Chassis":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/Chassis"},"Description":"Root Service","EventService":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/EventService"},"Id":"RootService","JsonSchemas":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/JSONSchemas"},"Links":{"Sessions":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/Sessions"}},"Managers":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/Managers"},"Name":"Root Service","Oem":{"Dell":{"@odata.type":"#DellServiceRoot.v1_0_0.ServiceRootSummary","IsBranded":0,"ManagerMACAddress":"d0:96:69:51:d4:70","ServiceTag":"XXXX"}},"RedfishVersion":"1.2.0","Registries":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/Registries"},"SessionService":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/SessionService"},"Systems":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/Systems"},"Tasks":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/TaskService"},"UpdateService":{"@odata.id":"/redfish/v1/UpdateService"}}
root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/opt# cat redfish.txt | jq .Systems
{
  "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems"
}
root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/opt# cat redfish.txt | jq .Systems | jq .@odata.id
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD, expecting QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.@odata.id
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.@odata.id
jq: 2 compile errors
root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/opt# cat redfish.txt | jq .Systems | jq .["@odata.id"]
{
  "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems"
}
"/redfish/v1/Systems"
root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/opt# cat redfish.txt | jq .Systems | jq .["odata.id"]
{
  "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems"
}
"/redfish/v1/Systems"
root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/opt#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the filter:

```
.Systems["@odata.id"]
```

That is, at a bash or bash-like prompt, you'd type something like:

```
jq '.Systems["@odata.id"]' redfish.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @peak ... tried but didn't work: `code` root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/tmp# cat redfish.txt | jq .Systems
{
  "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems"
}
root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/tmp# cat redfish.txt | jq .Systems["@odata.id"]
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): odata is not a valid format
root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/tmp#

Comment: You have not properly quoted the jq filter.  If you are having problems with quoting, I'd suggest putting the jq program into a file and using the -f command-line option.

Comment: my bad, pressed enter... and it auto posted b4 I got to post the output heh... output is now included above... `root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/tmp# cat redfish.txt | jq .Systems { "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems" } root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/tmp# cat redfish.txt | jq .Systems["@odata.id"] jq: error (at <stdin>:1): odata is not a valid format root@ubuntu-xenial:/var/tmp#`

Answer (score 0):

i stumbled across this, as this is the highest rated site for a duckduckgo query of "jq" and "@odata.id"

Unfortunately the answer is incorrect ... after some messing around I have got the correct answer:

```
jq '.Systems.[]"@odata.id"'
```

Since the things in the square brackets [] are an array that are a 0 indexed (start at zero) numeric array, you'll get an error trying to reference an element called "`@odata.id`" (i.e. `.Systems["@odata.id"]`), while `.Systems[1]` would work (if there are two elements in the array)

If you want all the elements ... use the above, if you want a specific element, you can use:

```
jq '.Systems[#]."odata.id"'
```

There should be an earlier component (in the output) that will tell you how many elements (hopefully), something like `"Members@odata.count"`

***BUT*** ... after i typed this and checked your data i realized i was solving my case, that looked like yours, but wasn't.  In actually looking at your data, what you need is ...

```
jq '.Systems."@odata.id"'
```

Because you DON'T have an array, you have have normal key that just needs proper quoting ...

Hopefully this helps